# login and registration page not jump to the dashboard after registration and login process

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm trying to create a Login and Registration page using this reference [Link](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-custom-authentication-login-and-registration-tutorial/)

I have done the same code, but after login, it does not jump to the Dashboard page, even after Registration also pages do not jump to the Dashboard, now I'm too confused why it's not working, what I have to do the wrong thing here.

please help me with this.

My code

**Web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomAuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

/*Route::get('', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});*/

Route::get('dashboard', [CustomAuthController::class, 'dashboard']); 

Route::get('login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('custom-login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom');

Route::get('registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'registration'])->name('register-user');
Route::post('custom-registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customRegistration'])->name('register.custom'); 

Route::get('signout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'signOut'])->name('signout');
```

**Path : E:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\app\Http\Controllers**
**CustomAuthController.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Admin;


class CustomAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }  
    
    public function registration()
    {
        return view('auth.registration');
    }

    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        //dd('login');
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');          
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {            
            //return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->withSuccess('Signed in');           
            return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }

    public function customRegistration(Request $request)
    {  
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
           
        $data = $request->all();
        $check = $this->create($data);
        
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('You have signed-in');        
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return view('dashboard');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('You are not allowed to access');
    }

    public function create(array $data)
    {
      return Admin::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
      ]);
    }    
        
    public function signOut() {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
  
        return Redirect('login');
    }
}
```

in this **CustomAuthController** there is a function **customLogin** and **customRegistration**
if condition is not work I think so.

**Path : E:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\resources\views\auth**
**registration.blade.php**

**

```
@include('header')   
  <div class="container-scroller">
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper full-page-wrapper">
      <div class="content-wrapper d-flex align-items-center auth px-0">
        <div class="row w-100 mx-0">
          <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="auth-form-light text-left py-5 px-4 px-sm-5">
              <div class="brand-logo">
                <!-- <img src="../../images/logo.svg" alt="logo"> -->
                <img src = "{{ asset('/images/logo2.png') }}" alt="logo"/>
              </div>
              <h4>New here?</h4>
              <h6 class="font-weight-light">Signing up is easy. It only takes a few steps</h6>
              <form class="pt-3" action="{{ route('register.custom') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Username">
                  @if ($errors->has('name'))
                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                  @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                  @if ($errors->has('email'))
                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                  @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                  @if ($errors->has('password'))
                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                  @endif
                </div>
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-muted">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                      I agree to all Terms & Conditions
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <!-- <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-medium auth-form-btn" >SIGN UP</a> -->
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-medium auth-form-btn">SIGN UP</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-4 font-weight-light">
                  Already have an account? <a href="{{ url('login') }}" class="text-primary">Login</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
  </div>
@include('footer')**
```

**Path : E:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\resources\views\auth**
**login.blade.php**

```
@include('header')
@extends('layouts.layout')
  
@section('content')
  <div class="container-scroller">
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper full-page-wrapper">
      <div class="content-wrapper d-flex align-items-center auth px-0">
        <div class="row w-100 mx-0">
          <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="auth-form-light text-left py-5 px-4 px-sm-5">
              <div class="brand-logo">
                <!-- <img src="../../images/logo.svg" alt="logo"> -->
                <img src = "{{ asset('/images/logo2.png') }}" />
              </div>
              <h4>Hello! let's get started</h4>
              <h6 class="font-weight-light">Sign in to continue.</h6>
              @if (Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ Session::get('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
              <form class="pt-3" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Username">                  
                  @if ($errors->has('email'))
                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                  @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                @endif
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <!-- <a class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-medium auth-form-btn" 
                  href="{{ url('login.custom') }}">SIGN IN</a> -->
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-medium auth-form-btn">SIGN IN</button>
                </div>
                <div class="my-2 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <!-- <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-muted">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                      Keep me signed in
                    </label>
                  </div> -->
                  <a href="#" class="auth-link text-black">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="mb-2">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-facebook auth-form-btn">
                    <i class="ti-facebook mr-2"></i>Connect using facebook
                  </button>
                </div> -->
                <div class="text-center mt-4 font-weight-light">
                  Don't have an account? <a href="{{ url('registration') }}" class="text-primary">Create</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
  </div>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

**Path : E:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\resources\views\dashboard.php**
**dashboard.php**

Comment: When you say "does not jump to the Dashboard page", where does it go?

Comment: @aceraven777 like after registration success its need to go on Dashboard page but its going on Login page, same things as Login page.

Answer (score 0):

In the registration, you're just creating the user, you're not logging the user in. Use `Auth::login($user);` to login the user.

In the login, you're using `redirect()->intended`, i think its intending to go to the login page instead of dashboard read [THIS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users) or [THIS](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/when-to-use-redirectintended-and-redirectto?page=0) to read more about `redirect()->intended`.

```
    public function customRegistration(Request $request)
    {  
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
           
        $data = $request->all();
        $user = $this->create($data);

        Auth::login($user);
         
        return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('You have signed-in');
    }

    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        //dd('login');
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {            
            return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }
```

Comment: i have doing this but its not work

Comment: infact i have added that alert message in login page its says Login details are not valid

Comment: But the registration works now right?

Comment: yes registration work but after registration its need to jump on dashboard but its jump on login page

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your new code in the controller?

Comment: i havent change new code in controller its remain same as I posted

Comment: So you didn't apply my answer here? You didn't change a thing?

Comment: i have applied but its not work

Comment: in registration i add thi code Auth::login($user); its gives error

Comment: i have updated my controller code

Comment: Your `$check = $this->create($data);` it should be `$user = $this->create($data);`

Comment: Login details are not valid
it shows this

Answer (score 0):

i think its just a syntax error. you have to implement a middle-ware for
protecting the routes from users to access without login

your `custom login` method should be like this

```
 public function authenticate(LoginRequest $request)
    {
         if(Auth::attempt([
          'phonenumber'=>$request->phonenumber,
         'password'=>$request->password],
           $remember=$request->has('remember')?true:false))
         {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
         }
    }
```

i hope it helps you if you having a doubt..
[Look after this github open repo](https://github.com/saravanasai/HospitalManagement.git)